# React Native - Why using the Systrace API?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, systrace

There is no documentation for `Systrace` api [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/systrace). Why using the `Systrace` API? A little example case will be more appreciated. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

To write events to the systrace log.  Which is a debugging tool.  See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/systrace for more info.

Comment: So, how to implement it? Can you please do a little example?

Comment: You wouldn't unless you really are looking at low level ui or network timing issues. It's something the people wiring react native night use, but it's probably not something anyone wiring on to of it ever will